# AjaxFileUpload error in ie8 only AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In only ie8, I get "error raising upload complete event and start new upload". I have scoured the internet for a solution for days but to no avail.  Below is my web.config file.  Per other posts, I have added the AjaxFileUploadHandler to System.Web and System.Webservice, as well as added preCondition="integratedMode". This does not do it for ie8, which I must support.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1000000" executionTimeout="360"/>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Set-Cookie" value="BALANCEID=DARPDINAProduction_Internet.node1;domain=.cc.cnh.com;path=/;"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to remove one little line in the [AjaxControlToolkit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.html) source code:

```
iframe.security = "restricted";
```

Keeping that line in there makes ie treat the iframe with the same level of security as a site in the user's "Restricted" list.